# IIS-10 worker processes crashing

Tags: reporting-services, iis-10, application-pool, windows-server-2019, sqlfilestream

We recently upgraded our server O/S from Win2012 to Win2019. While on 2012, in IIS, we had configured a Virtual Directory called PDFReader. The physical path was a filestream directory which contains a series of PDFs, which is essentially just a UNC share.

The directory was being called by an SSRS report & its sole purpose was to call the PDF from filestream and render it in SSRS.

We used a simple virtual directory when we were on Windows 2012 which worked fine. But we noticed that the app pool kept crashing on 2019. So that led to me convert it to an application because that way, I could assign an individual app pool to it & manage the rapid fail protection settings as a band-aid for now until we could identify the underlying issue. That has been getting us by.

I tried a few things such as changing the application pool identity to LocalSystem, then a privileged domain user w/SQL Filestream access. I also tried changing the .NET CLR Version to "No Managed Code" and the pipeline from Integrated to Classic. The latter seemed to slow the failures slightly, but nevertheless the problem persists.

Here's the stacktrace which we consistently see every few minutes as users frequently pull up PDFs.

Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.17763.1, time stamp: 0xa7ccada2
Faulting module name: nativerd.dll, version: 10.0.17763.1, time stamp: 0x84a81d7a
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000a8f0
Faulting process id: 0x25cc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d921151b65f242
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\nativerd.dll
Report Id: 88535cc3-8716-40f7-bfab-1f53f9c77b92
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Fault bucket 1192683016347496699, type 1
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: w3wp.exe
P2: 10.0.17763.1
P3: a7ccada2
P4: nativerd.dll
P5: 10.0.17763.1
P6: 84a81d7a
P7: c0000005
P8: 0000a8f0
P9:
P10:

There are a number of PDFs that are called which one might consider large, over 20MB with a handful of them over 100mb.

As for the user experience, since I implemented the rapid fail protection, the user doesn't run into the 503 errors anymore, requiring me to start the stopped app pool. Occasionally, when the worker process dies & hands off to the next one spawned, it's a minor delay.

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

- Converted virtual directory to application.
- Created/assigned individual app pool to application.
- Changed rapid fail protection settings to allow for 25 failures in 10 minutes instead of the 5/5 out of the box.
- Changed application pool identity to LocalSystem... Problem persisted. So I changed to a privileged domain user/local admin with proper SQL filestream rights, same behavior.
- Ensured nativerd.dll was present in system directory, no discernible permissions issues.
- Looked into MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB registry key associated with nativerd.dll per a Microsoft KB article, but I don't see that key present in the registry.
- Ran DebugDiag analysis with this summary result:

In w3wp__PDFReader__PID__160__Date__06_15_2022__Time_08_39_35AM__249__Second_Chance_Exception_C0000005.dmp the assembly instruction at nativerd!INDEXED_ARRAY_LIST::FindEntry+18 in c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\nativerd.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to read from memory location 0x00000038 on thread 6

Comment: For native crash like that `0xc0000005`, one feasible option to troubleshoot the cause is to analyze the actual crash dump. All you tried before knowing the root cause might not help much. If you need assistance on that, open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I forgot to mention that I did download DebugDiag & ran an analysis. It did create a rather verbose dump for review at the time of crash, but nothing I could glean useful. Ideally, we'd open a case with MS, but with funds tight, I've been tasked to try & resolve on our own without paying for a support case at this time.

Comment: Then I am afraid you cannot easily save time and money the same time. Dump analysis has a rather steep learning curve, so even with a dump at hand (the dump name you shared indeed shows the right dump you got), you might not be able to figure out the exact data you need (especially for native dumps). Either you gain that knowledge yourself, or you buy that experience from others.

Comment: As you discussed, the error could be caused by several reasons. I suggest you seek support from Microsoft support.